# wordpress shortcode A executing code from shortcode B

Tags: plugins

I am having a problem with wordpress. I have created some shortcodes in wordpress. None of them use hyphens as suggested by the wordpress codex.

One is for validating a user email (just a success or fail) in which in case of success, I add this e-mail address to a mailchimp mailing list.

Antother is just to test mailchimp subscription functionality.

Problem is that when the user validation page is executed it always fires the mail no matter what. If I remove the shortcode in the test page, this stops.

I am really puzzled.

Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/7wHwxc5q

Comment: maybe take your api key out of your code, just so noone could take advantage out of this.

Comment: obviously that is not the real api key...

Comment: yeah, I was to quick

Answer (score 0):

in your test you do this.

```
line117 of pastebin
 $retval = $api->listSubscribe($listId, 'my@mail.com' );
```

which most likely will do the subscribe and send the email? or am I missing something?
so whenever you call your `flashusers_chimptest.php` it is subscribed no matter what.

Comment: but I'm not calling flashusers_chimptest.php in the other shortcode, so it should not get fired